# MATLAB exiting loop in function when using GUI

Tags: user-interface, matlab, loops, stack, exit

I have a function which runs when a button is clicked and that function will call another function to perform plotting, which is an animation composed by a series of loops. Problem is, after the program is run, it cannot be stopped unless pressing Ctrl+C which then cause the whole .exe to fail and require reopening it.

I want to make a Reset button, so to stop the loop from running, but how to pass a new variable from the interrupt to the existing function which is two level above the stack?

Thank You

edit @ 22:13 27/3/2011 (UKT)

a more clearer of what I am trying to do:

```
function push_calculate_Callback(hObject, eventdata, handles)
    (List of parameters read in the GUI)
    fmain(list of paramters required to pass to the function, fmain)
```

that's first part of the code which linked directly to the GUI, the fmain looks like:

```
function fmain(List of parameters)
(List of calculations...)
fplotting(list of paramters for plotting)
```

in which the fplotting is where the animation comes out from, inside the fplotting:

```
function fplotting(list of parameters)
for i = 1:(end)
    (do the animation plot)
end
```

here is the loop where I want to stop when I press the reset button. coz if anyone press Ctrl+C when the animation is undergoing (looping), it will give an error and the exe file will crash and requires reopening it. So what I want it be able to stop it when someone press the reset button.

If I use persistent, the new value, after I press the reset button, it will not pass into the existing loop and break the loop... looks like I am looking for a way to update the parameter after I have change it outside the function

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use exit or quit to exit the program

To stop the loop from running, you can use break or return from a function..

Comment: I guess that's not the way to solve any GUI related problem...

if you put return into you Callback, it will just return you with nothing; 

if you put "break", well, technically you can't put break coz you don't have a for / while loop in the callback function

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet might be to use a [PERSISTENT](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/persistent.html) variable whose state you check at each iteration of the loop in function 2, and whose value you modify in the "reset"-callback.

**reset callback**

```
function reset_callback(hObj,eventdata,handles)
   %# "activate" persistent variable
   persistent breakThis
   %# set it to 1
   breakThis = true;
```

**function with the loop**

```
function functionWithTheLoop(someInput)
   ...
   %# "activate persistent variable
   persistent breakThis
   ...
   %# start loop
   for iter = 1:numOfIterations
      %# check whether you need to break out of the loop
      if breakThis
         %# reset the function value
         breakThis = false;
         break;
      end    
      ...   
   end
```

Comment: I have just edited the question to make it more clear, hope it helps to identify my problem, thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You can use application data information, i.e. [`setappdata`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/setappdata.html) and [`getappdata`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/ref/getappdata.html):

```
% animation loop function
function loop(hFig)
   setappdata(hFig, 'run', true);   % here or somewhere else...
   while(getappdata(hFig, 'run'))
      plot(....);
   end
end

% GUI stop-loop btn callback
function stop(hFig)
   setappdata(hFig, 'run', false);
end
```

I guess that would work.

Comment: @Thomas: Please leave comments using the `add comment` link.